# Adding Subviews programmatically vs. adding them in InterfaceBuilder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a beginner's question.

I was wondering about the level of subviews and how to determine them. Consider having put one button in IB (sampleButton) and then creating a subview programatically, like so:

```
[view insertSubview:aView atIndex:[view.subviews count]];
```

which is simply equivalent to:

```
[view addSubview:aView];
```

Now, in both cases, my index (which is referred to as z, right?) should be 1, if I am not mistaken.

I have one button added to my view in IB which should be at index 0 (z = 0, or do they start at one?). Then, if I do a view.subviews count, this will give me the number 1, as I have 1 object at index 0. So my new subview 'aView' will be placed at index = 1 which is just one layer above my sampleButton.

So far so good. But what if I did not want things to be this way? What if I wanted to be the sampleButton at a higher level (e.g. 1) and my 'aView' at the lowest (e.g. 0)? Can I simply do this:

```
[view insertSubview:aView atIndex:0];
```

Will this simply take care of my button created in IB, pushing it to another layer or will I have to tell IB that sampleButton shouldn't be at z=0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behaves as you already guessed: if you insert a subview at index 0 it is "below" all the other subviews.

Comment: alternative `[view bringSubviewToFront:aView]`
will do the same

Comment: i would say seega's alternative actually is the right and only correct solution as the OP mentions those views have already been added as subviews within IB.

Comment: @Seega: Thanks, I think this is what I was actually looking for.